# Elastic search query builder with multi value fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have multi value fields like field A can have data like ("x", "y" ),("x"),("y", "z") and ("x","z"). Suppose client want to query ElasticSearch to fetch those values of A where A = "x", in such case I wanted to return only 1 record where A = ["x"], but TermQueryBuilder would return wherever it found "x" i.e ["x", "y" ],["x"], ["x","z"]

```
 final BoolQueryBuilder termQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        termQueryBuilder.must(new TermQueryBuilder(filter.getDimension(), filter.getValue()));
        return termQueryBuilder;
```

Please let me know how can I ensure it would return only 1 record, only the exact match data should get returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), along with the term query, to filter documents based on the provided script.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['A.keyword'].length == 1",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "A": "x"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "70343831",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.15965708,
        "_source": {
          "A": [
            "x"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @priyadhingra19 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks much!!! for posting this here, how do write the same in java. I found few java syntax for scrip query builder. - QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("doc['A.keyword'].length == 1")); how should I append term query in the same ?

Comment: @priyadhingra19 you need to use a bool query and include filter and must clause in it

Comment: @priyadhingra19 are you able to create boolean query using Java ?